# Power query pivot column with multiple records

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

How can I pivot a table where there is more than one record for a given column heading?  See images below - I have transformed data so that it's listed by date, and I want to pivot the table so that there is one column for each date, with the corresponding records.  I have tried multiple ways using pivot column, group by column, etc. - but I can't seem to get what I need.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very weird requirement, but because this is Power Query then: yes we can.  They key is to calculate a grouped running count which will drive the row numbers in your output.  Following your sample data, Order 99292, 99391, 99397 etc would all get a running count = 0, then 99384, 99404 etc would get running count = 1.

Having derived the grouped running count, then you just need to Pivot on **start_date**, choosing **Custom** as your Values field and setting the Advanced / Aggregate Value option = **Don't Aggregate**.

There are a few different techniques around to calculate a grouped running count.  I've used my favourite and put together a demo in my OneDrive folder:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AGLFDsG7h6JPgw4

It's the file: **Power Query demo - pivot column with multiple records**

Comment: Mike, I think I understand what you're saying - I'm not seeing that file in the link provided, but I will try to build a custom column following your logic. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my OneDrive sync broke. The file should be visible now. Try List view and Sort by Modified.